Scalar and quantitative problem with code to define null and void counterparts in binary partitions
I'm currently working on code for an equation dictating the values of "null" and "void, using these motives as baseline material the code is to quantify ley lines of isotopes, properties of photonic reactants and uses time as a parameter of isotope density decay invoking fundamental properties of gravity from the "gravatomic spectrum" as a constant.
This is the code I tried:
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint

# Define the function representing the differential equations
def system(y, t, phi0, lambda_val, epsilon):
    rho, phi, r = y
    
    # Isotope density decay equation
    drho_dt = -lambda_val * rho
    
    # Change in energy of photonic reactants equation
    dphi_dt = phi - phi0
    
    # Gravitational force equation
    F = G * epsilon / r**2
    
    # Properties of the gravatomic spectrum equation
    sigma = F / dphi_dt
    
    return [drho_dt, dphi_dt, sigma]

# Define initial conditions
rho0 = 1.0  # Initial isotope density
phi0 = 0.0  # Baseline energy of photonic reactants
r0 = 1.0    # Initial distance

# Set parameters
lambda_val = 0.1  # Decay constant
G = 6.67430e-11   # Gravitational constant
epsilon = 1.0     # Efficiency factor of gravitational interaction

# Create time points for integration
t = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)

# Initial values
y0 = [rho0, phi0, r0]

# Solve the system of ODEs
sol = odeint(system, y0, t, args=(phi0, lambda_val, epsilon))

# Extract the solutions
rho_sol = sol[:, 0]
phi_sol = sol[:, 1]
sigma_sol = sol[:, 2]

and this gave two errors with them being:
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in scalar divide sigma = F / dphi_dt ODEintWarning: Illegal input detected (internal error). Run with full_output = 1 to get quantitative information. sol = odeint(system, y0, t, args=(phi0, lambda_val, epsilon))

Hi. (1) The error message is telling you "Run with full_output=1 to get quantitative information." Did you try that? (2) In the code you showed us, you define a function system, but then you never use it. Yet you get an error about line sigma = F / dphi_dt from that function. It seems you are not showing us everything?

tried using full_output=1 but it says excess accuracy requested
